# npm: how to restrict dependencies+versions in sub-modules of the project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Assume that at the product level is a NPM package that imports other npm packages built by various sub-teams in the project. We use Webpack for bundling.

```
MyProduct(An NPM package)
    - libA (NPM package by team A)
    - libB (NPM package by team B)
    - ...
```

What options are available to restrict dependency libraries+version used by the sub-modules owned by various teams in the project?

Is there something like

1. the Maven BOM feature for NPM packages?
2. a plugin that checks the package version during build of the product or the individual libraries?

Comment: Both NPM and Yarn have a lockfile.  I don't know if they're hashed or whatever beyond that, but the lockfile is probably what you're looking for.